# AlarmManager launching Alarm more than once for a setRepeating() time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an alarm set to go off everyday at 8:00 oclock with this code.

```
String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(alarm);
Intent intent = new Intent("NEW_ITEM");
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
Log.e("RELEASE LIST", "ALARM Set For 1 day from " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

The only problem is the alarm goes off more than once. I dont want this. As it can be very annoying for the same message to keep reoccurring. Is there something in my code i am missing or need to do to fix this?

EDIT:

```
                if(doc != null){

                     item = doc.select("tr>  td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");
                    if(item != null){
                        // Iterator over those elements     
                    ListIterator<Element> postIt = item.listIterator();   



                    while (postIt.hasNext()) {    


                        Element name = postIt.next();
                         nameOf = name.text();


                      form = postIt.next().text();


                        Element url = name.select("a").first();
                         urlString = url.attr("href");


                         genre = postIt.next().text();


                        Date = postIt.next().text();

                         Log.v("Dates", Date);



                             if(Date.contains(dayOfMonth)){ 

                                 i++;


                         }  
                         }
                       }
                    }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void notUsed){
                if(i == 0){

                }

                else{



     if(i==1){
     nm = (NotificationManager) ReleaseService.this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
              CharSequence from = "GameIT";
              CharSequence message = "You have "+i +" Today!";
              PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(gameReleaseService.this, 0, new Intent(ReleaseService.this, Htmlparser.class), 0);
              Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                      "You have "+i +" Released Today!" , System.currentTimeMillis());
              notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                      notif.setLatestEventInfo(ReleaseService.this, from, message, contentIntent);
                      nm.notify(i, notif);

 }else{
     nm = (NotificationManager) ReleaseService.this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
              CharSequence from = "GameIT";
              CharSequence message = +i+ " released today!";
              PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ReleaseService.this, 0, new Intent(ReleaseService.this, Htmlparser.class), 0);
              Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                       "You have "+i+" that released today!" , System.currentTimeMillis());
              notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                      notif.setLatestEventInfo(ReleaseService.this, from, message, contentIntent);
                      nm.notify(i, notif);




             }
            }
            }
```

Comment: `goes off more than once` what do you mean? what is happening?

Comment: After it inially launches at 8 oclock everyday. it them goes off like every other couple of hours or so.

Comment: Your code seems correct.. tell us about the Activity show us some code that may be error! Is there anychance that it is retrying? no?

Comment: It could be because when the alarm is launched it launches a service that pasrses come content and then sets a notification depending on the content...Im guessing this may be where the error is..something that is making it reloop it self and keep showing the notification. Ill post it in my question

Comment: Check out my edit..I thinking something is happening here that keeps relaunching the notification..Or what do you think?

Comment: no it is impossible to send the notification twice according to your code... this is in onStartCommand ?

Comment: What do you mean onStartCommand?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3833/discussion-between-sherif-and-coder-for-life22)

Comment: the code you posted! is it in the function `onStartCommand()` of the service or is it in the `onCreate()`? you must put it in `onStartCommand()`

Comment: Its in onCreate)() why does it matter if its not?

Comment: put it in the onStartCommand! because onCreate is called many times!

Comment: Okay so ive read the docs on onStartCommand(). Ive moved my code to this. Does the service automatically stop once this is called and finished?

Comment: no service stopping depends on how you called it... Do you want me to prepare some code to use a Binder.. ? 1 more thing there is a problem! if this code is responsible for sending a notification then the real bug is in ur other code.. please search for all the places where you call the service!

Comment: Listen please check where you start the alarm... because maybe you are starting 2 alarms .. where do you start the alarm?

Comment: I start it in onBoot and in my Main Activity.

Comment: A broadcast reciever to handle setting the alarm when the device is rebooted

Comment: oh but you must check if the alarm is already on! not to put alarm again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Calendar getNextDateNotify(Context context) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int dayOfMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (dayOfMonth < 15) {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
        } else {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
        //cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12); //?
        int hour = generateRandomFromTo(9, 20);
        if (hour < 12) {
            cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
        } else {
            cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, (hour - 12));
        }
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        // SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a");
        // Log.d("TAG", df.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis())));
        return cal;
    }
```

But this method only for my purposes. For yours you must modify it.

Comment: SO basically mine would be cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8); is that all or would i need more like yours?

Comment: cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12); 
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM); or  cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //alarm for tomorrow 8:00 am or 8pm

Comment: my method for me:
1st and 15th of each month at random time between 9am and 8pm

Comment: but you must make check for today time to start alarm

Comment: What do you mean? (Im not to familar with alarm manager) first time really using it.

Comment: 1)Why is your hour_of_day 12? - Sorry, this from other place.
2) What do you mean? (Im not to familar with alarm manager) first time really using it  -  for example you start your application (for example you start your alarm only when your app start first time after installation) at 9am(you need to plan your alarm at 8am) - so you need plan first your alarm for tomorow 8am. If you start you app at 6am - so you need to start your alarm today at 8am

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have more than one alarm going on.

Do you check which alarm you are receiving when the event is triggered?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is your error. Try to use one short alarm and bind it with a receiver where you can restart this one short alarm.

```
public static void scheduleNextAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123454322, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = getNextDateNotify(context);//modify it for yourself(add one day for calendar object)
    if (cal == null)
        return;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

In your receiver

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Utils.scheduleNextAlarm(context);
```

I hope this code will be useful for you.

Comment: I dont get it..Sorry. Could you explain in greater detail how this is related to my problem?

Comment: <<After it inially launches at 8 oclock everyday. it them goes off like every other couple of hours or so. – >>
With my above code I have not any similar problems.(Above code was for quite different task but maybe this approach will be useful for you.)

Comment: What is the getNextDateNotifiy()?

Comment: public static Calendar getNextDateNotify(Context context) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  int dayOfMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  if (dayOfMonth < 15) {
   cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
  } else {
   cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);